# htaccess redirection exceptions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?type=Navigation&action=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?type=Navigation&action=$1

Options All -Indexes
```

which sends everything to index.php in the root folder. But in my structure i have something like

```
/root
   /.htaccess
   /index.php
   /files
   /intranet
```

i was wondering if there is a RewriteRule exception so that when i type www.mysite.com/intranet it goes to the 'intranet' folder without passing trough the index.php file

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  I believe you just put a rule before the others with the url you do not want rewritten, and specify that it shouldn't be rewritten using `-` like so:

> RewriteRule ^intranet/.*$ - [L]

Comment: Probably needs [L] option to prevent the other rules from being processed.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, actually it was a problem in my server... you code works :)

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/intranet\/?
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$ index.php?type=Navigation&action=$1 [L]
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works as well but the other guy posted the answer earlier... so i'll give him the correct answer. anyways yours work perfectly. thanks! :D

Comment: No probleme, but to add an other RewriteRule is IMHO no best practice. With RewriteCond(itions) you can add additional checks to your rule set. You don't have to make sure, that the other RewriteRule stands first.